# Display div while parent is display None

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div that is like this

```
<div style: "display:none;">
   <div class="displayMe">
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to how to make the div displayMe show while keeping the parent Div hidden

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: This is not technically possible. Perhaps if you explain your use case we could suggest an alternate approach

Comment: What @RaduAndrei said, unless you move it somewhere else in the DOM

Comment: If this situation is coming in your html then I would say you should think of changing your markup appropriately.

Answer (score 8):

you can use this:

```
//this class for parent div
.hide {visibility: hidden;}
//this class to the child div
.reshow {visibility: visible;}
```

Comment: Hah, beat me to it. +1

Comment: The parent `<div>` would take up content though, perhaps that's unwanted

Comment: @Teemu, What do you mean?

Comment: @BryceSiedschlaw I was after the same as ckuijjer, but it seems it can not be achived by sizing the invisible parent.

Comment: @Teemu I still don't quite understand what you mean. I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9a5srkj/) to try and test what you're saying but it seems to work to me. It doesn't matter what the parent's size is, the child element still shows. Can you clarify your comment?

Comment: Setting `visibility: hidden` for parent, it still takes the space as if it was visible. Adding some content to `#red` in [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yc0xa8a/), demonstrates what I mean.

Comment: @Teemu Ah, I see what you mean now. Thanks for the clarification. That's something to definitely look out for.

Answer (score 3):

It's not totally clear, where exactly you want to show the visible part of the hidden parent. Here's a pure CSS solution, which more or less replaces the parent with a child on screen.

As you can see, there's a drawback in this solution concerning the rest of the content on the page. However, setting `display:none` removes the hidden element taken space from the textflow, hence this is probably exactly what would happen, if it was possible to show elements inside none-displayed elements.

```css
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    Text in the wrapper<br/>
    more text ...<br/>
    ... and one more line.
    <div id="content">Some visible content</div>
    This text is below the visible
</div>
<div>This is outside of invisible</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. You could instead move/clone the child element and insert it somewhere else in the markup (e.g. via JavaScript).

```
var element = jQuery('.Inner-Div').clone();
```

and then append to any visible element that be appropriate.

```
element.appendTo('some element');
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/xmo9bpot/

**EDIT**

Another clever way would be to `hide` all siblings of the chosen child element and in fact leave the parent visible

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/xmo9bpot/1/

```
$(".child").siblings().hide();
```

Comment: Your second solution, pure genius!

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, as container should be visible when you want to display its child,

explain your scenario so much relevant solution can be provided, or you can try following 
If you have multiple divs inside parent div, and you want to display any one child div at a time using jquery/javscript, then you can arrange your divs as

```
<div>
   <div id="div1" style="display:none;">
   </div>

  <div id="divq" style="display:none;>
   </div>

  <div id="div3" style="display:none;>
   </div>

</div>
```

then write your javascript / jquery code as

```
if (YourCondition == 1)
{
  $('#div1').show();
}

else if (YourCondition == 2)
{
  $('#div2').show();
}


if (YourCondition == 3)
{
  $('#div3').show();
}
```

Cheers !

Answer (score -2):

```
.displayMe{display:block !important}
```